# Oracle sql - Errors creating a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've created this procedure

```
create or replace procedure enrollstudent(
    rno in STUDENTS.ROLL_NUMBER%type,
    sname in STUDENTS.STUDENT_NAME%type,
    cid in STUDENTS.COURSEID%type,
    cfees in STUDENTS.FEES%type,
    spercent in students.percentage%type
)as 
    discount number;
begin 
    discount := spercent*5;
    cfees := cfees-discount;
    insert into STUDENTS values(rno, sname, cid, cfees, spercent);
    commit;
end;
```

that works with this table

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
    ROLL_NUMBER  NUMBER(20)   NOT NULL,
    STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    COURSEID     NUMBER(20)   NOT NULL,
    FEES         NUMBER(20)           ,
    PERCENTAGE   NUMBER(20)
);
```

When I run the procedure creation I have a `Procedure ENROLLSTUDENT compiled` and it gets created but i have the following errors in the compiler log

```
Error(8,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(8,1): PLS-00363: expression 'CFEES' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

If I try to run the procedure with some data I simple have `PLS-00905: object [schema].ENROLLSTUDENT is invalid`

Answer (score 2):

CFEES is an IN parameter.  You can't change it.  Create a local variable, and
use that, example:

```
cfees2 NUMBER := cfees;
cfees2 := cfees2 - discount;
insert into STUDENTS values(rno, sname, cid, cfees2, spercent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define and calculate any local variables; you can do the computation of `cfees` in place (right in the `INSERT` statement):

```
create or replace procedure enrollstudent(
    rno in STUDENTS.ROLL_NUMBER%type,
    sname in STUDENTS.STUDENT_NAME%type,
    cid in STUDENTS.COURSEID%type,
    cfees in STUDENTS.FEES%type,
    spercent in students.percentage%type
)as
begin 
    insert into STUDENTS values(rno, sname, cid, cfees-spercent*5, spercent);
    commit;
end;
/
```